# How to make minimap run in specified modes?

Tags: emacs

I installed GNU minimap (version 1.2).

When I open certain type of files , e.g. .py, .c, the minimap comes out as expected.

However, when I open .html file, the minimap is not started.

Is there a way to add additional modes where the minimap automatically shown?

I tried to add hooks to .emacs file but it just starts minimap-mode, but no displaying any minimap.
`(add-hook 'html-mode-hook 'minimap-mode)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, `minimap-mode` only works for modes that derive from `prog-mode` (most modern modes for programming, including `python-mode` and `c-mode`). Modify `minimap-major-modes` if you want to activate it for others, e.g.

```
(setq minimap-major-modes '(prog-mode html-mode))
```

or

```
(add-to-list 'minimap-major-modes 'html-mode)
```